# First time going Serverless - how is the learning curve? Do you recommend using a third party framework?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

Currently looking into setting up a personal project on a Serverless model. Considering AWS Lambda, but open to other providers. The question is, does anyone have experience using serverless component frameworks (i.e. Serverless:  https://serverless.com/framework/) in addition to going directly through AWS or a similar provider? If so, do you have a recommendation for someone who has not setup a serverless model before (whether or not to use a framework)? For reference, I've worked with traditional cloud services in the past, and this project involves financial data and machine learning, and has a client facing front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you'll want to make sure serverless is right for the project. Serverless architecture is fantastic, but bear in mind it's not always the right solution.

To answer your question, I have experience with both AWS Lambda on its own and with Serverless (the specific framework you linked). Serverless (the framework) handles a lot of the complexity for you, and is definitely worth looking into if you're building data pipelines (which it appears you are). That being said, I would recommend getting familiar with the serverless architecture first, and then using a framework like Serverless after you know what you're doing. Learning curve isn't too bad.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. Sounds like it's worth spending some time learning the architecture. Recommend any tutorials?

Comment: Sure thing. Check out this blog post https://dashbird.io/blog/best-places-to-learn-serverless/